# Can you explain what AspectJ's cFlow(P && Q) does by means of example?

Tags: java, aspectj

I'm currently going through AspectJ's documentation, and I don't quite get their point on [Pointcut composition](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/language-joinPoints.html#pointcut-composition). In particular, I don't understand what `cFlow(P && Q)` does, when advice with that pointcut would get executed.

A [PowerPoint presentation](http://www.cs.uu.nl/docs/vakken/aop/aop3.ppt) (for a course at the university of Utrecht) I found explains

> cflow is the collection of join points flowing from the argument
>   pointcut. This means that cflow(P) && cflow(Q) is the intersection of
>   the two collections, while cflow(P && Q) means that you first combine
>   the pointcuts P and Q, and all the join points flowing from that are
>   in this collection.

They go on to list all join points for `cFlow(P) && cFlow(Q)` (`pointcut flowPAndflowQ() : cflow(execution(* Example.P(..))) && cflow(execution(* Example.Q(..))) && within(Example);`), and to me it looks like an [intersection](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/da/Set_intersection.svg/320px-Set_intersection.svg.png) of all the control flow points of the individual statements - P ∩ Q, if you will (just like they said):

> Flow from P - execution(void Example.P())
>   Flow from P - call(void Example.Q()) 
>   Flow from P - execution(void Example.Q()) 
>   Flow from Q - execution(void Example.Q()) 
>   Flow from P && flow from Q - execution(void Example.Q())

(Their example is like the one in the AspectJ docs, except for the lacking println() statement.)

What I (still) don't understand, is what `cFlow(P && Q)` would do.

Does it mean "get all join points that are in P, then add all join points that are in Q, then match on anything that flows from any of them"? If so, I don't get the println() statement for the AspectJ example: `System.out.println("should not occur");` Surely, if I add all flow points in P and Q (i.e. `P + Q`), that should be the superset (union) to P ∩ Q, [P ∪ Q](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ee/Union_of_sets_A_and_B.svg/314px-Union_of_sets_A_and_B.svg.png)?

Or does it mean "get all join points in P that are also in Q", i.e.
 all flow points within `X()` below?

```
public void P() { X(); }
public void Q() { X(); }
public void X() { /* all that is in the body of X() */ }
```

Or can it just never occour, as AspectJ's example states? (Why?)

I'd really appreciate if someone could shed some light. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it mean "get all join points that are in P, then add all join
>   points that are in Q, then match on anything that flows from any of
>   them"?

No, it means get all join points that are in P and in Q so it's intersection.

> Or does it mean "get all join points in P that are also in Q", i.e.
>   all flow points within X() below?

Yes for "get all join points in P that are also in Q" and no for the remaining part. The reason is pointcut P defines a single join point: execution(void Example.P()), and pointcut Q defines a single join point: execution(void Example.Q()). Because these join points are different the intersection for them is an empty set. cflow taken from an empty set is an empty set too. That's why in AspectJ documentation this pointcut is marked with "should not occur".

Hope this helps!

This is a misleading quote from the Power Point presentation:

> cflow(P && Q) means that you first combine the pointcuts P and Q, and
>   all the join points flowing from that are in this collection

The word "combine" should be replaced with "intersect".

I created a simple example on Github that replicates the example from the PowerPoint presentation: https://github.com/medvedev1088/aspectj-cflow-composition-example

```
public class Example {
    public void P() {
        Q();
    }

    public void Q() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example().P();
    }
}
```

If you run it the output should be like this:

```
pointcut: P                    join point: execution(Example.P())
pointcut: flowP                join point: execution(Example.P())
pointcut: flowP                join point: call(Example.Q())
pointcut: Q                    join point: execution(Example.Q())
pointcut: flowP                join point: execution(Example.Q())
pointcut: flowQ                join point: execution(Example.Q())
pointcut: flowPAndflowQ        join point: execution(Example.Q())
```

What this shows is that there are only 3 join points:

```
A: execution(Example.P())
B: call(Example.Q())
C: execution(Example.Q())
```

Pointcuts:

```
pointcut P includes only A
pointcut Q includes only C
pointcut flowP includes A, B and C
pointcut flowQ includes only C
pointcut flowPAndflowQ includes only C
```

We can see now that P && Q is an empty set while flowP && flowQ includes C.

I also included additional pointcut: cflow(P() && publicMethods()) (the advice for this pointcut is commented out in the code). publicMethods() is execution(public * *(..)). Unlike cflow(P() && Q()) it doesn't result in empty set.

Comment: I think I'm even more confused now. So, `cflow(P) && cFlow(Q)` is the intersection (of join points downstream of (and including) the two pointcuts), and `cFlow(P && Q)` is also an intersection, but different from the first one? Is that because the later only looks at the initial pointcuts, but not the join points "downstream"? Is there maybe an example you can construct that shows how the later works? :)

Comment: >>Is that because the later only looks at the initial pointcuts, but not the join points "downstream"?

That's correct.
>>Is there maybe an example you can construct that shows how the later works?

I updated my answer. Please checkout the example project on Github https://github.com/medvedev1088/aspectj-cflow-composition-example. Hope it will clarify things.

Comment: Thanks for the example & thanks for trying to make me see the light. I'm not sure I'm entirely there yet; I'll look into it again tomorrow, with a fresh mind. I did send my question to the [AspectJ list](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/aspectj-users/msg14760.html), however, shortly before you updated your response. Just for my own sake, I wrote `cFlow(P && Q)` out as
`pointcut cFlowPandQ : cFlow(execution(* Example.P()) && execution(*
Example.Q())) && within(Example);`
So, is the whole point that you can't execute P and Q at the same time?
(Isn't that what happens when P calls Q, though?)

Comment: >> So, is the whole point that you can't execute P and Q at the same time?
Exactly. At any given point of the execution of a program you can be only at one join point. So when P calls Q the join point is call(Example.Q()). The execution(Example.P()) join point happened before call(Example.Q()). The execution(Example.Q()) happens after call(Example.Q()).

Comment: So, `cflow(P() && publicMethods())` works because it's essentially different names (pointcuts) for the same join point at the same time? (`pcut: P -> jn  pts: execution(Example.P())` and `pcut: execPublicMethods -> jn pts: execution(Example.P()), execution(Example.Q())`, so both pointcuts get triggered when `Example.P()` gets executed - what I don't get then is why I get the following: `pcut: flowPAndPublic -> jn pts: execution(Example.P()), call(Example.Q()), execution(Example.P())` for `cflow(P() && publicMethods()) && within(example.Example)`; I would now only have expected the first one..)

Comment: You are right.
P() && publicMethods() is equivalent to just P(). This is because when you intersect the 2 sets of join points you get only execution(Example.P()) which is equal to P(). This means that cflow(P() && publicMethods()) is equivalent to cflow(P()) which includes the 3 join points. :)